# Not able to use p4 module in python

Tags: python, p4python

I am using ubuntu 12.04 64 bit and i have installed p4python in it..  I tried to import p4 module but it is giving me below error

import p4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named p4

Can someone please help me??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try

```
import P4
```

The Module has been renamed

New module name

```
    The P4Python module has been renamed from p4 to P4. For example:

    Old:
    >>> import p4
    >>> p4c = p4.P4()

    New:
    >>> import P4
    >>> p4 = P4.P4()
```